# Template array of pointers to objects of child classes as argument for a function

Tags: c++, arrays, object, pointers, dynamic-arrays

I have a few classes that inherit the same class with a print method. I also have a custom-made dynamic array template class. I have created a few dynamic arrays of pointers to objects from the child classes. For every array I want to have a separate function for calling all the print methods of the objects pointed by the pointers- some times I want to print only the "weapons", sometimes only the "modifications" or sometimes everything. So far I have tried two solutions- copy-pasting the first method (as shown in the code) for every array or converting the dynamic arrays into arrays of pointers to the "mother" class and passing the new ones as an argument to an universal print function.

And here is some code:

```
    class Item {...}
    class Modification : public Item {...}
    class Equipment : public Item {...}

    DynamicArray<Modification*> modification;
    DynamicArray<Equipment*> weapon;

    //The first way:
    void printModsInfo ()
    {
        if (modification.size() == 0)
            cout<<"No mods in inventory\n";
        else
            for (int i = 0; i < modification.size(); i++)
                modification.returnElement(i)->printInfo();
    }

    void printWeaponsInfo ()
    {
        if (weapon.size() == 0)
            cout<<"No weapons in inventory\n";
        else
            for (int i = 0; i < weapon.size(); i++)
                weapon.returnElement(i)->printInfo();
    }

    //The second way:
    void _printModsInfo ()
    {
        Item** tempRef = new Item*[modification.size()];//array of pointers
        for (int i = 0; i < modification.size(); i++)//converting DynamicArray<Modification*> into Item** tempRef
            tempRef[i] = modification.returnElement(i);
        printCertainStuffInInventory (tempRef, modification.size());
        delete tempRef;
    }

    void _printWeaponsInfo ()
    {
    Item** tempRef = new Item*[weapon.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < weapon.size(); i++)
        tempRef[i] = weapon.returnElement(i);
    printCertainStuffInInventory (tempRef, weapon.size());
    delete tempRef;
    }

    void printCertainStuff (Item** arr, int size)
    {
        if (size == 0)
            cout<<"Nothing from this type in inventory...\n";
        else
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                arr[i]->printInfo();
    }
```

So I have two choices: copy-paste the five rows from the fist way, or copy-paste the more complicated five rows from the second way and add five more rows for the printing function. But what I really want to do is to simply pass the dynamic arrays as arguments and make the conversion (if needed) in the printing function- or to simply call the "printer" by writing: `printCertainStuff(modification);` (or "weapon" or whatever). And this is required by the design of the whole project. I did consult my teacher, but the answer was that there is no way to do that without converting before calling the function.

But still- is there a way to pass such dynamic arrays as arguments the way I want?

Comment: Listen to your teacher.

Comment: I tried other ways, and yes- there really is no other way.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% clear on what you're wanting, but if it is to combine all your print methods you could try using a template:

```
template< class T >
void printInfo ( const T& arr, const char* failmessage )
{
    if (arr.size() == 0)
        cout<<failmessage;
    else
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++)
            arr.returnElement(i)->printInfo();
}
```

And then to use for weapons you'd go:

```
printInfo( weapon, "No weapons in inventory\n" );
```

And similarly for modifications.